# Curl command to query Rally not abiding by page size parameter

Tags: rally

I am trying to use a curl command to query for all my projects within my workspace.  When I specify a page size, ex. 100, the result only returns 19 projects instead of my total number of projects which is over 50.  Why is my curl command not abiding by the page size parameter?

Browser REST Client - This returns all projects correctly. 
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project?workspace=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/1234567890&query=&start=1&pagesize=100

Curl command - I only get 19 projects, and the result json said "pagesize=20" even though my curl command query said pagesize=100 
% curl -u 'user@company.com:' https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project?workspace=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/1234567890&query=&start=1&pagesize=100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a different URL. Instead of

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project?workspace=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/1111&query=&start=1&pagesize=100
```

try:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/1111/Projects?&pagesize=100"
```

Here is a curl command:

```
curl -v -u user@co.com:secret "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/1111/Projects?&pagesize=200" | python -m json.tool > /home/user/curloutput
```

the purpose of this part:

```
| python -m json.tool > /home/user/curloutput
```

was to prettify the json response and to save it to a file to make it easier to examine.

pagesize=200 worked. There are 24 projects in this workspace. The same command, without pagesize=200,  returned 19 projects, but URL that includes pagesize=200 returned all 24.

Comment: Hi nickm. How to bind my page size parameter for this url. I tried. But no use.    url     = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?query=((Project.Name%20%3D%20%22" + teamNameEncoded + "%22)%20and%20(Iteration.Name%20%3D%20%22Sprint%20" + key['sprintNumber'] + "%20" + key['sprintEndDate'] + "%22))&fetch=Name,FormattedID,PlanEstimate"